# GenericViewSet------TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hello I'm new to Django RestFramework, I'm trying to implement Genericviewset but I keep getting this error " TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable "
my code is as follows
views.py----

```
class exampleviewset(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    serializer_class=exampleSerializer
    queryset=example.objects.all
```

What might be the reason for this error?

Comment: Can you add more details??

Comment: queryset=example.objects.all()

Comment: thanks, #bmons..... my bad;)